# Display log of changes to the branch in svn

Tags: svn, commit

I have a brach (actually a folder with a copy) in /braches/me that I have checkout into /home/me/project/branch how can I check all commits I've done to that branch. I've try to `svn log .` but it show me log from other users, but only I commit changes to that branch.

So how can I display log for the branch (directory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your code changes only in `/branches/me`? You can do this:

```
$ svn log --stop-on-copy -v $REPO/branches/me
```

This will show you all changes on `/branches/me` and will contain other people's commits on `/branches/me`, but I assume you're the only one using this particular branch. The `--stop-on-copy` will proven the log from going down the branch to where it was copied from `trunk` and down `trunk`.